# JavaFX/SWT WebView combine FX DND with SWT DND

Tags: java, eclipse, webview, swt, javafx

I need to make WebView's drag events available as SWT drag events.
For example, whenever a drag event in a WebView (DOM Element is dragged, contentEditable=true) I need to trigger an equivalent SWT drag event that is sent instead, so, I can re-use SWT APIs.
Anyone did this already and can provide some hints on how this could be achieved?

Just realized that SWT's DNDEvent is package protected and cannot be instantiated from outside. There would be workarounds, but not sure if I would be on the right track at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Use the `StructuredSelection` from JFace](http://georgiangrec.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/swt-composite-drag-and-drop/). I think this should work with your `WebView` as well.